# Find the First Order With a Statement (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables which looked like:

```
user_dataset
+------+---------------+------------+
|userid| Register_time |    Country | 
+------+---------------+------------+
|    1 |  03/02/17     |      TW    |     
|    2 |  20/03/17     |      SG    |     
|    3 |  26/03/17     |      PH    |   
|    4 |  05/02/17     |      VN    | 
|    5 |  01/10/17     |      ID    | 
|    6 |  03/09/17     |      MY    |  
|   ...|  ........     |      ...   | 
+------+---------------+------------+

order_dataset
+--------+--------+------------+--------+------------+
|orderid | userid |    itemid  |  gmv   | order_time |
+--------+--------+------------+--------+------------+
|1030132 |  3     |  3366770   |  27,0  |  24/04/17  |   
|1030137 |  5     |  6130641   |  69,0  |  02/02/17  |     
|1030147 |  1     |  6770063   |  87,0  |  25/04/17  |    
|1030153 |  6     |  4193426   |  82,0  |  05/11/17  |   
|1030155 |  4     |  8825994   |  29,0  |  03/07/17  |   
|1030160 |  2     |  5660916   |  44,0  |  30/01/17  |   
|....... | ...    |      ...   |  ...   |     ...    |   
+--------+--------+------------+--------+------------+
```

I need to write an Query: to find the first order GMV of each user and if there is a tie, use the order with the lower orderid.

How to achieve that? Thank you in advance

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: Easy in MySQL 8.x. More convoluted in MySQL 5.x

Comment: Specify the expected result as well, having the table data already specified. (Any tie there?)

Comment: Note that dates in MySQL adhere to a specific format.

Comment: @jarlh I use MySQL80

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select u.*,
       (select o.gmv
        from order_dataset o
        where o.userid = u.userid
        order by order_time, orderid
        limit 1
       ) as earliest_gmv
from user_dataset u;
```

Performance will be greatly helped with an index on `order_dataset(userid, order_time, orderid)`.

Answer (score 0):

I woul build iut this way

```
    select * from order_dataset a 

    where not exists(select 1 from order_dataset b where a.userid  = b.userid 
                      and a.order_time < b.order_time and a.orderid < b.orderid )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(user_dataset), MIN(order_time), GMV FROM order_dataset
    GROUP BY user_dataset;
```

I don't think there's a need to bring in the user_dataset for this question

Comment: Correct in that the user dataset is likely not needed, but your query grouping isn't likely to work, as there's no grouping on the GMV column.  It also won't tell which order is the first one.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.